# How to create a Filename + Queryparameter Request

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing a page with a list of files. Every file should be previewable and downloadable. Therefore every file needs two anchor-links. One for download and one for preview. The download-link was no problem as the mediatype is always "application/octet-stream" but the preview link must pass the filename with extension as the request url so that the browser can create a specific request for the mediatype that is given by the filename extension. In addition to that filename I want to pass a query parameter which is the id of the file, as there can be multiple files with the same name.

So my controller method for preview looks something like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/show/{filename}", produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody byte[] show(@RequestParam("fileid") Long fileId, Model model)
{
    ...
}
```

The thymeleaf template anchor looks like that:

```
<a th:href="@{/files/show/${file.filename}(fileid=${file.id})}" style="height:24px;" title="Preview">
```

As seen the filename should be a route-parameter and the id is a query-parameter. Thymeleaf however creates the following url:

```
/files/show/${file.filename}?fileid=13
```

It successfully inserts the fileid and creates a queryformat but it fails to replace the filename.
Am I doing something wrong? What is the correct format for a thymeleaf link of that kind?

Answer (score 1):

The [standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) supports both path paramters and normal parameters in the same expression.  In general, I would avoid string concatenation when building links.

Here's how I would format this:

```
th:href="@{/files/show/{filename}(filename=${file.filename}, fileid=${file.id})}"
```

Comment: I have never seen this form. Seems to be the most elegant solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok...After more research I could solve it myself. The right form of the thymeleaf URL is one of the two:

```
th:href="@{'/files/show/' + ${file.filename}(fileid=${file.id})}"
```

of

```
th:href="@{|/files/show/${file.filename}(fileid=${file.id})|}"
```

Both will work.